# Unable to set "never" to "show battery status in menubar"?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-panel, gnome-shell-extension

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome shell.  I have tried to remove battery icon from panel using the battery setting in system settings but to no avail.  I use an extension called "system Monitor" which shows the battery properties but when I am removing the battery option in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js` the "system monitor" icon also disappearing.

So I tried "evil status" but to no avail, also tried `sudo apt-get remove idicator-power` with out any result. The problem is it is appearing at the moment I plug-out the power connection & not disappearing when I again powering it up . Where am I making the mistake ?

Thanks,
Mrinal.

Answer (score 3):

Install dconf-tools, open dconf Editor in System Tools then click on com/canonical/indicator/power. In the right panel choose icon-policy "never"